# JavaScript template engine - extract placeholder name from template

Tags: javascript, templates

Is there any JavaScript template engine which lets you extract placeholder names? For example:

```
const template = 'Hi {{ name }}!';
const compiledTemplate = SomeTemplateEngine.compile(template);

console.log(compiledTemplate.extractPlaceholders()); // ['name']
```

Comment: please, no regexp solutions ;)

Comment: I just found this, looks simple enough. http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Javascript-template-engine-in-just-20-line
But since it's JS, off course it uses regexp :P

Comment: Native ES6 ? https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a template engine called [olojs](https://github.com/onlabsorg/olojs/blob/master/README.md) that may do what you need.

Installation:

```
npm install @onlabsorg/olojs
```

Usage:

```js
const olojs = require('@onlabsorg/olojs');
// or require('@onlabsorg/olojs/browser') if you want to use it in the browser

const evaluate = olojs.document.parse("My name is <% name: 'Marcello' %>!");
const context = olojs.document.createContext({/* preset variables here */});
const {text, data} = await evaluate(context);
// data: {name: 'Marcello'}
// text: "My name is Marcello!"
```